# Return a set of unique pixel values in a raster with PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, pyqgis, values

I am trying to test whether a value exists in a raster against all the values present.  I am using pyqgis (Python 2.7) in in QGIS 2.14.  I have found a number of ways to get point location values and even to list all values, but I cannot find a way to return a set of unique values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
lyr = iface.activeLayer()
# or
# lyr = QgsRasterLayer("path/to/raster.tif", "raster_data")

rows = lyr.height()
cols = lyr.width()
dpr = lyr.dataProvider()    

bl = dpr.block(1, dpr.extent(), cols, rows) # 1: band no

unique_values = list(set([bl.value(r, c) for r in range(rows) for c in range(cols)]))
```

`unique_values` also contains no data value. It may take a long time based on raster size.

Comment: Thanks, Kadir.  This works like a charm.  To the moderators who want to  put this on hold, I assume because I did not include code - sorry, I thought it would be better to briefly describe the types of code I tried rather than waste space with any of the attempts I made that didn't work.  I had no code that came close.